# Порядок аргументов в assertEqual

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Не смог найти однозначный ответ на следующий простой вопрос: как в `assertEqual` должны располагаться аргументы? Сначала ожидаемый результат, затем фактический или наоборот? Существует ли общепринятая устоявшаяся практика в Python сообществе?

Официальная документация и стандартная библиотека этот момент однозначно не определяют. В самой `assertEqual` аргументы просто `first` и `second`.

`assertEqual(actual, expected)`

- смотрится несколько более интуитивно на мой взгляд: "этот вызов функции должен возвращать это значение", что плюс
- на месте фактических результатов могут помещаться выражения разной длины - в результате глаз не сразу натыкается на ожидаемое значение, что минус

`assertEqual(expected, actual)`

- несколько более популярный вариант в других языках, насколько я могу судить
- ожидаемое значение сразу бросается в глаза

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом с технической точки зрения разницы нет никакой, очевидно. В самом деле, если посмотреть на исходный код, то в конце окажется, что сравнение идет просто через `==`. Докстринг к `TestCase.assertEqual`:

> Fail if the two objects are unequal as determined by the '=='
>   operator.

На практике чаще вариант `assertEqual(actual, expected)`. В документации к различным библиотекам/фреймворкам обычно именно в таком варианте, в статьях и на SO как-то тоже. Как вы и сказали, он интуитивный, возможно поэтому.

Comment: Считаю важным отметить, что если `__eq__` вдруг переопределяется и в нём есть какой-нибудь баг, то от перемены мест сравнимаемых может и что-нибудь упасть